# How to identify the font the browser rendered

Tags: css

I have a css like

```
body ,html ,* {
font-family: "MyTest1","MyTest2","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif !important;
}
```

How to identify from the above fonts which one the browser rendered the page finally?

Comment: As a developer you don't need to know which one is used...

Comment: This has to be one of the stupidest comments I've come across on SO

Answer (score 2):

You can check it out in Chrome Dev Tools in Elements tab and than at the bottom will be Rendered Fonts.

Comment: I m using Chrome. Yes, I see the rendered fonts option. TY

Answer (score 1):

in `browser developer option` available

`inspect element` using `mouse right click` or `F12` function key you can see which `font` is apply in `Elements option`

Answer (score 0):

A way to log this information in the console would be using `window.getComputedStyle()`.

Example:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.hello-world');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(text)
console.log(style.fontFamily)
```

```css
.hello-world {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="hello-world">Hello, world!</p>
```